# Troubleshooting Java DateFormat Month Parsing Issue

Tags: java, date-format

I am running into some odd output using the Java, DateFormat object. For some reason it is adding one to my month and I am not sure why. I have broken down the problem as simple as possible.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author djc39_000
 */
public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Date testDate;
        try {
            testDate = (Date) formatter.parse("12/6/2013 11:23:04 AM");
            System.out.println(testDate);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sun Jan 06 11:23:04 EST 2013
```

Expecting Output:

```
Fri Dec 06 11:23:04 EST 2013
```

Also, if I change the month to 11 in my string it does not change the month in the stamp. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Solution was found, mm is for mins, and I used for month which should have been MM.

Are there any other characters that might be easily confused for bonus points?

Comment: _"Are there any other characters that might be easily confused for bonus points?"_ Read the sections date and time patterns : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: As a general practice for quick debugging of SimpleDateFormat patterns, I use the format to print new Date() and make sure the format produces the current time in the format I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date format should be "**MM**/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"